# Jquery can't register click on fetched data

Tags: php, jquery

Ok so for my administrator page I have it retrieving table rows from a php file using ajax... this is what it returns to my administration page and it all displays correctly on the admin page

```
while ($row = $lquery->fetch()){
     echo "<tr><td><span class=\"tbltext\">". $row['username'] ."</span><span class=\"tbledit\">Edit</span></td></tr>";
}
```

This is my jquery in my administration page, for now I'm just trying to get it to alert me

```
$('.tbltext').click(function(){
  alert('working');
});
```

But it is not registering the click, is it because the html is imported and there is something special I have to do in order to get it to be clickable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For elements that will get added/replaced later in the DOM, you can use the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function to delegate the event handler to an element higher up in DOM tree:

Try:

```
$(document).on('click', '.tbltext', function(evt){
  alert('working');
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I figured it was something like that, just couldn't find the answer by Googling

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
   $('.tbltext').live("click", function(){
      alert('working');    
   });
```